# Gather output of sp_helpuser for all databases of a SQL Server instance at once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently, `sp_helpuser` has to be executed for each database of a SQL Server instance separately.

Does anyone have a script that will give `sp_helpuser` like output for all databases at once?

Comment: Third link on Google searching for ["sp_helpuser all databases"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sp_helpuser+all+databases&oq=sp_helpuser+all+databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like below. Not sure about SQL Server 2012 but works in SQL Server 2008 R2. mentioning so cause `sp_msforeachdb` is undocumented SP and is not guaranteed to work in future release.

```
sp_msforeachdb 'use [?] print ''?''; exec sp_helpuser;';
```

**EDIT:**

See the below post with exact code samples. This is exactly what you are looking for or trying to achieve.

[TSQL: Audit user roles for all databases](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/tsql-audit-user-roles-for-all-databases/1085/)

**EDIT1:**
Complete code from the post I have mentioned. Have tried myself in SQL2008R2 and warks like charm.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#user_table') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #user_table;
END;

-- tmp Table to hold the user data
CREATE TABLE #user_table
(
    ServerName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Database] NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
    UserName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    GroupName NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
    LoginName NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
    DefDBName NVARCHAR(256) NULL,
    DefSchemaName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    UserID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [SID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
);    

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '

    DECLARE @name SYSNAME,
            @sql_string NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Cursor containing all users for the current database context
    DECLARE usr_name CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT [name]
                                          FROM sysusers
                                          WHERE hasdbaccess = 1
                                          AND [name] NOT LIKE ''#%''
                                          AND [name] NOT IN (''guest'');

    OPEN usr_name;
    FETCH NEXT FROM usr_name INTO @name;

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) -- This loop processes each database
    BEGIN

        -- if it''s a windows login surround with square brackets
        IF (@name LIKE ''%\%'')
        BEGIN
            SET @name = ''['' + @name + '']'';
        END

        SET @sql_string = N''EXEC sp_helpuser '' + @name;

        INSERT INTO #user_table
        (
            UserName,
            GroupName,
            LoginName,
            DefDBName,
            DefSchemaName,
            UserId,
            [SID]
        )
        EXEC(@sql_string); 

        -- Add Server &amp; database name to dataset
        UPDATE #user_table
        SET ServerName = @@SERVERNAME,
        [Database] = DB_NAME()
        WHERE ServerName IS NULL
        AND [Database] IS NULL;

        -- Get the next database user
        FETCH NEXT FROM usr_name INTO @name; -- Get next user

    END

    -- Clean up
    CLOSE usr_name;
    DEALLOCATE usr_name;';

-- Add USE database statement to change db context
SET @sql = 'USE ?; ' + @sql;
-- Execute the string for each database
EXEC sp_MSforeachDB @sql;


SELECT *
FROM #user_table
ORDER BY LoginName, [Database];
```

Comment: Care to explain the reason for downvote? Is the answer wrong? In such case I shall discard the answer.

Comment: Already tried this. This script gives the output, but doesn't give the database name. Also, gives seperate boxes for each database, difficult to copy it into excel for every database. 
And, i haven't downvoted.

Comment: @dingchak, that's alright and I didn't meant that you downvoted. Neither I care about the downvoter. BTW, what you are actually trying to achieve with `sp_helpuser`? please exapling a bit more. so that I can help further.

Comment: I need to get all user permissions of the SQL Instance which contains 15 databases in a format similar to the output of sp_helpuser. sp_helpuser is currently to be executed per single database. And the script that you gave above does the work, but doesnt show up for which database it is and it gets hectic for reporting purpose.
Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Looks good. But i keep getting the below error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: @dingchak, can't be. I tried myself before posting the link to you and it works flawlessly. anyways, have pasted the entire code in my answer. Just copy/paste and execute it.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a lot Rahul.